# Configurable custom code

Tags: c, architecture, refactoring

Our customer provided source code has portions of code that will be executed based on tool type. A sample code portion is given below. The function has common portions and tool specific(hardware platform) portions. The code is written in C and runs in VxWorks. Addition or deletion of new tool type has code modification. The customer wants addition or deletion new tool type with minimal code change and testing effort

```
int vsp_recv(char *const recv_text)
{
    int rc  = 0;
    const int       type =  get_tool_type();
    // Common Code  

    if (MODEL_CR == type)
    {
        rc = beamoff(recv_text);                
    }
    else
    {
        rc = vsp_set(recv_text);
    }

    return(rc);
}
```

Is it the right technique to separate the code to two methods as given below, keep them in separate source files and define separate make files to generate tool specific binary? Is there any better ways to do this?

Tool type MODEL_CR code

```
int vsp_recv_tool_speccific(char *const recv_text)
{
    return beamoff(recv_text);              
}
```

Tool type MODEL_CV code

```
int vsp_recv_tool_speccific(char *const recv_text)
{
    return vsp_set(recv_text);              
}
```

Refactored method

```
int vsp_recv(char *const recv_text)
{
    int rc  = 0;
    const int       type =  get_tool_type();
    // Common Code  

    rc = vsp_recv_tool_speccific(recv_text);                
}
```

Comment: Looking at the your MODEL_CR code and MODEL_CV code, I assume you need device specific function for the return value. If you have one method to detect all models, does it mean you must include all device specific libraries in the projects? For this reason, I vote for using separate source files and makefile options.

Answer (score 0):

Define a shared library for each tool and a configuration file that defines what functions get called for each tool.  Load the shared libraries at startup and provide a signal catcher to reload if the configuration file changes.

Answer (score 0):

the OPs question (and posted code) says that 3 places will need to be modified.

1. the function: `get_tool_type()`
2. the header file with the definitions of `MODEL_CV`, `MODEL_CR`, etc
3. the `if-then-else` list.

were it me, I would implement a table of function pointers, have `get_tool_type()` return an index into that table.  Then all the if/then/else code would become a single statement that invokes a function from the table.

Then any updates would be additions to the table, modifications to 'get_too_type()`, and the additional functions like`beam_off()`

The loss of a tool type would not require any code change.

the addition of a tool type would require appending an entry to the table, mod to `get_tool_type()` to recognize the new tool, and the new function to process the new tool type.

Of course, this could result in code that is never executed.